# In the Soundcloud Javascript SDK, how do I correctly send a 'filter' parameter to the '/tracks' endpoint?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm trying to filter my tracks search to return only tracks that are "streamable."

```
SC.get('/tracks', { q: query, filter: "streamable" }, function(sound) {
    console.log(sound);
});
```

The way I have it written above, I'm still getting tracks that have the "streamable" property set to false.

The documentation is vague regarding how to properly include this parameter(https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks):

> filter    enumeration (all,public,private,streamable,downloadable)

Has anyone tried this before? What is the proper way to send this parameter and filter the results to include only streamable tracks?

Answer (score 0):

streamable-filter is boolean. try do it that way:

```
SC.get('/tracks', { streamable:true}, function(sounds) {
for (i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) { 
   console.log(sounds[i].stream_url + ' - '+ sounds[i].streamable);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/s74apqfs/